# getCheckedRadioButtonId() on RadioGroup unchecked value not given correct using data binding android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to use validation on radio group. But i can see the if no radio button is not checked the return value of getCheckedRadioButtonId() is not -1. I am using databinding.

The xml file of radio group.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/LabRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/sound">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_normal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="@{Exams.result.equals(@string/Exam_Normal)?true:false}"
        android:text="Normal" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_abnormal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="@{Exams.result.equals(@string/Exam_Abnormal)?true:false}"
        android:text="Abnormal" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_unknown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="@{Exams.result.equals(@string/Exam_unknown)?true:false}"
        android:text="Unknown" />

</RadioGroup>
```

[image]

Here is the debug value in the screen shot.

Java code

```
private boolean Validation() {
    int radiogroup = binding.LabRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if (binding.LabRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
        binding.radioNormal.setError(CommonMessages.GROUP_RADIO_ERROR_TAG);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You have set the `checkedButton` attribute in your `RadioGroup` in your `xml`. I think you get the Id of this button.

Comment: not working ... can you show an example

Comment: What have you done..? I didn't add any instruction ._. Have you removed the `android:checkedButton="@+id/sound"` line?

Comment: no i didn't .. I tried with   int i = binding.sound.getCheckedRadioButtonId();    got an error as Error:(238, 15) error: cannot find symbol variable sound

Comment: Remove the mentioned line, please. Also, you did not provide any `View` with the `id` `sound` in your post.

Comment: Thanks it working now ..... Please provide the answer so that I can mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the `checkedButton` attribute in your `xml`:

```
<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/LabRadioGroup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:checkedButton="@+id/sound">  //<--- remove this line
```

You get this `id` back, even if nothing is checked.

Comment: I would have thought OP is getting the error because @+id/sound is not one of the RadioGroups children.  Shouldn't it be "@+id/radio_unknown" or radio_abnormal or radio_normal?

Comment: He set the checkedButton to this? And apparently Android doesn't care.